# OpenGL ImageViewer

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have been trying to make an ImageViewer in OpenGL. But I don't know how to hide specific parts of my vectors/textures in OpenGL.

The ImageViewer should be an exact copy of an UIScrollView with paging enabled, where the images fill the whole screen.

The neat thing in UIScrollView is that you can set the actual frame of the UIScrollView, and set the content size, so when the image gets slided out of the frame, you won't be able to see the image anymore.

I need some guidelines so I can continue researching what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can setup your fragment shader to make pixels invisible when they are out of range.

You know the position of the 4 vertices (top-left,top-right,bottom-left,bottom-right) and the position of the texture. You can then upload a uniform vec4 to the fragment shader containing the minimum and maximum x and y sizes of the window. You then calculate if a pixel is inside or outside that area. If inside: actual color, if outside: gl_fragcolor=vec4(1,1,1,0);

Is this any help?

Comment: I found a solution myself, but your solution could work too, although a bit different, but I upvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.

I put an UIScrollView that fills the whole screen, and use that offset to move the texture coordinates.

I don't know if this is the optimal solution, but I don't have any performance problems etc. So it is good enough for now.

If you have better solutions, feel free to suggest them.